# copying files from multiple directory to another multiple directory

Tags: scripts, copy

let assume, I have two folders; folder_1 and folder_2. There are another 24 folders in each folder (folder_1 and folder_2). Each sub-folder of folder_1 contains 1 text file whose name is geomagnetic_script_xxxx. xxxx is variable numeric, "geomagnetic_script" is constant for all folders. Sub-folders of folder_2 are empty. I need to copy each text file (geomagnetic_script_xxxx) into the sub-folder of folder_2. In this way each sub-folder of folder_2 contains 1 text file which is identical to sub-folders of folder_1.

Which script allow me to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this command in the folder containing `folder_1` and `folder2`:

```bsh
find folder_1 -name 'geomagnetic_script_????' -type f -print0 | while read -d '' -r file; do echo cp "$file" folder_2/"${file#*/}"; done
```

Just for safety I inhibited the actual `cp` command by prepending `echo` to it. See if it's doing what you want and then remove the `echo` and run it again.

Sample output on my machine:

```
$ tree
.
├── folder_1
│   ├── subfolder_1
│   │   └── file_25406
│   ├── subfolder_10
│   │   └── file_1439
│   ├── subfolder_11
│   │   └── file_21028
│   ├── subfolder_12
│   │   └── file_13026
│   ├── subfolder_13
│   │   └── file_3717
│   ├── subfolder_14
│   │   └── file_9825
│   ├── subfolder_15
│   │   └── file_14953
│   ├── subfolder_16
│   │   └── file_12760
│   ├── subfolder_17
│   │   └── file_8490
│   ├── subfolder_18
│   │   └── file_14577
│   ├── subfolder_19
│   │   └── file_11999
│   ├── subfolder_2
│   │   └── file_24557
│   ├── subfolder_20
│   │   └── file_27957
│   ├── subfolder_21
│   │   └── file_158
│   ├── subfolder_22
│   │   └── file_1361
│   ├── subfolder_23
│   │   └── file_27370
│   ├── subfolder_24
│   │   └── file_4919
│   ├── subfolder_3
│   │   └── file_30149
│   ├── subfolder_4
│   │   └── file_5352
│   ├── subfolder_5
│   │   └── file_27907
│   ├── subfolder_6
│   │   └── file_14716
│   ├── subfolder_7
│   │   └── file_1989
│   ├── subfolder_8
│   │   └── file_7850
│   └── subfolder_9
│       └── file_31831
├── folder_2
│   ├── subfolder_1
│   ├── subfolder_10
│   ├── subfolder_11
│   ├── subfolder_12
│   ├── subfolder_13
│   ├── subfolder_14
│   ├── subfolder_15
│   ├── subfolder_16
│   ├── subfolder_17
│   ├── subfolder_18
│   ├── subfolder_19
│   ├── subfolder_2
│   ├── subfolder_20
│   ├── subfolder_21
│   ├── subfolder_22
│   ├── subfolder_23
│   ├── subfolder_24
│   ├── subfolder_3
│   ├── subfolder_4
│   ├── subfolder_5
│   ├── subfolder_6
│   ├── subfolder_7
│   ├── subfolder_8
│   └── subfolder_9
└── script.sh

50 directories, 25 files
$ find folder_1 -type f -name 'file_*' -print0 | while read -d '' -r file; do cp "$file" folder_2/"${file#*/}"; done
$ tree
.
├── folder_1
│   ├── subfolder_1
│   │   └── file_25406
│   ├── subfolder_10
│   │   └── file_1439
│   ├── subfolder_11
│   │   └── file_21028
│   ├── subfolder_12
│   │   └── file_13026
│   ├── subfolder_13
│   │   └── file_3717
│   ├── subfolder_14
│   │   └── file_9825
│   ├── subfolder_15
│   │   └── file_14953
│   ├── subfolder_16
│   │   └── file_12760
│   ├── subfolder_17
│   │   └── file_8490
│   ├── subfolder_18
│   │   └── file_14577
│   ├── subfolder_19
│   │   └── file_11999
│   ├── subfolder_2
│   │   └── file_24557
│   ├── subfolder_20
│   │   └── file_27957
│   ├── subfolder_21
│   │   └── file_158
│   ├── subfolder_22
│   │   └── file_1361
│   ├── subfolder_23
│   │   └── file_27370
│   ├── subfolder_24
│   │   └── file_4919
│   ├── subfolder_3
│   │   └── file_30149
│   ├── subfolder_4
│   │   └── file_5352
│   ├── subfolder_5
│   │   └── file_27907
│   ├── subfolder_6
│   │   └── file_14716
│   ├── subfolder_7
│   │   └── file_1989
│   ├── subfolder_8
│   │   └── file_7850
│   └── subfolder_9
│       └── file_31831
├── folder_2
│   ├── subfolder_1
│   │   └── file_25406
│   ├── subfolder_10
│   │   └── file_1439
│   ├── subfolder_11
│   │   └── file_21028
│   ├── subfolder_12
│   │   └── file_13026
│   ├── subfolder_13
│   │   └── file_3717
│   ├── subfolder_14
│   │   └── file_9825
│   ├── subfolder_15
│   │   └── file_14953
│   ├── subfolder_16
│   │   └── file_12760
│   ├── subfolder_17
│   │   └── file_8490
│   ├── subfolder_18
│   │   └── file_14577
│   ├── subfolder_19
│   │   └── file_11999
│   ├── subfolder_2
│   │   └── file_24557
│   ├── subfolder_20
│   │   └── file_27957
│   ├── subfolder_21
│   │   └── file_158
│   ├── subfolder_22
│   │   └── file_1361
│   ├── subfolder_23
│   │   └── file_27370
│   ├── subfolder_24
│   │   └── file_4919
│   ├── subfolder_3
│   │   └── file_30149
│   ├── subfolder_4
│   │   └── file_5352
│   ├── subfolder_5
│   │   └── file_27907
│   ├── subfolder_6
│   │   └── file_14716
│   ├── subfolder_7
│   │   └── file_1989
│   ├── subfolder_8
│   │   └── file_7850
│   └── subfolder_9
│       └── file_31831
└── script.sh

50 directories, 49 files
$
```