# How to copy files from multiple directories, adding the parent folder's name to the filename?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, batch-rename

I have been looking to all possible answers about "copying file from multiple directories to one single directory" but I cannot find my answer. I need something slightly more specific for my database treatment.

I have a similar question to:

[copying files from multiple directory to another multiple directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/751869/copying-files-from-multiple-directory-to-another-multiple-directory)

but how can I copy these files (they all have exactly the same name) to a new directory and add them the parent directory name, so that I can recognize from which directory they were copied ?

Yes I could copy and rename each of name one after the other, if I hadn't 100 of them :)

I tried loops with find . etc, but still, I cannot add the copied files the parents directory name.

I am still junior in this field, and so I am starting with regex. I guess there is something to do here with them, but I cannot figure out how exactly.

So, this is my question graphically. How to do that with a simple command, or a loop, on my unix terminal:

```
DIR_a1 --> output_file.bam
DIR_a2 --> output_file.bam                              
DIR_a3 --> output_file.bam
```

Copy all `output_files.bam` in `NEWDIR_output` so that they appear with parent directory name:

```
output_file_a1.bam
output_file_a2.bam                              
output_file_a3.bam
```

***In advance, very thankful for any input***

Comment: Could be done easily, but not with a "simple command" as far as I can see. Is this on Ubuntu? It matters. If so, what version?

Comment: yes this would be done in Ubuntu terminal, the latest version 16.04

Answer (score 2):

#### Copying files from a source- into a target directory, adding the containg folder's name to the file

The script below will copy files *recursively* from a source directory into a *flat* directory, adding the name of the (direct) superior directory to the file's name. The directory's name will be inserted *before* possible extension on the file, exacvtly like your example.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys
import shutil

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
    for f in files:
        # split off the superior directory's name
        dirname = root.split("/")[-1]
        # define file+path, possible extension position
        src = os.path.join(root, f); spl = f.rfind(".")
        # defining new filename
        newname = f[:spl]+"_"+dirname + f[spl:] if spl != -1 else f+"_"+dirname
        # copy the file into the new directory
        shutil.copyfile(src, os.path.join(sys.argv[2], newname))
```

#### How to use

1. Copy the script intyo an empty file, save it as `copyandrename.py`
2. Run it with the source- and target directories as arguments:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/copyandrename.py <source_directory> <target_directory>
   ```

   My test command was e.g.

   ```
   python3 '/home/jacob/Bureaublad/pscript_4.py' '/home/jacob/Bureaublad/testmap' '/home/jacob/Bureaublad/target'
   ```

As always, please test on a sample first!

Comment: Thank you very much for this very complete response! I will try it in a while and let you know. This looks like a super script. .. However, I don't want to be impertinent and apologizes for not having point it out before, but for the moment all my script are in bash, and I would like, whenever possible, to make this step also in bash so that I can run a single script on my data processing at once.  But I keep your answer as priceless for it's precision. Bests,

Comment: @Marylaure just curious, but did you try?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this using the shell's parameter substitution features e.g.

```
$ for d in DIR_a*; do echo cp -- "$d/output_file.bam" "NEWDIR_OUTPUT/output_file${d#DIR}.bam"; done
cp DIR_a1/output_file.bam NEWDIR_OUTPUT/output_file_a1.bam
cp DIR_a2/output_file.bam NEWDIR_OUTPUT/output_file_a2.bam
cp DIR_a3/output_file.bam NEWDIR_OUTPUT/output_file_a3.bam
```

Remove the `echo` once you have checked that it is doing the right thing.

Comment: OK! thank you it works superb with my data. I will however change the mv command with cp or scp, because this has removed my entire files (that I deleted after the test... sig) For chance, I kept a copy of them on another computer :) Well, thank for this, of great help at my level!

Comment: Oh! sorry about that, I have corrected the answer. Shouldn't have posted before coffee :(

Comment: no worries, this was a good focus test for me, eheh Murphy is sad today :)