# Add to a prefix filename the name of its directory

Tags: 14.04, command-line, files, rename

l have about 100 directories such as :

- walking,
- writing,
- dancing,
- swimming.

Each of these directories contains a set of files.

l would like to add the prefix name of the directory to the filenames of its files.

For instance:

```
writing :
0ZPQl5QUvo0_000202_000212.mp4  
AFV8x8ezN8g_000016_000026.mp4  
-HutuMqTAPw_000275_000285.mp4 
qtvsw6h3yQo_000228_000238.mp4  
Ub0rc6U6nfI_000100_000110.mp4
```

becomes :

```
writing :
writing_0ZPQl5QUvo0_000202_000212.mp4  
writing_AFV8x8ezN8g_000016_000026.mp4  
writing_-HutuMqTAPw_000275_000285.mp4 
writing_qtvsw6h3yQo_000228_000238.mp4  
writing_Ub0rc6U6nfI_000100_000110.mp4
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Typical bash coding problem :-)

Comment: Almost similar, but just not https://askubuntu.com/questions/795426/how-to-copy-files-from-multiple-directories-adding-the-parent-folders-name-to?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a slightly improved version of your script - the main differences are

- using a shell glob `*` in place of `$(ls)` - see [Bash Pitfall #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)
- quoting any variable expansions (allows filenames with whitespace or other funny characters - see [Bash Pitfall #2](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cp_.24file_.24target))
- marking the end of options to `mv` using the `--` GNU extension - this lets it handle filenames that start with hyphens as well

So

```
for d in *; do 
  [[ -d "$d" ]] && cd "$d" || continue
  for f in *.mp4; do 
    echo mv -v -- "${f}" "${d}_${f}"
  done
  cd -
done
```

Or, more portably, you can loop over `./*.mp4` to protect from leading hyphens - but then you have to strip it off during the `mv`

```
for d in *; do 
  [ -d "$d" ] && cd "$d" || continue
  for f in ./*.mp4; do 
    echo mv -v "${f}" "${d}_${f#./}"
  done
  cd -
done
```

In either case, remove the `echo` (and the `-v` if you wish) once you are sure that it's working how you expect.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved using the following script :

```
for i in $(ls); do                                                 
  if [ -d $i ]; then                      
     fname=${i##*/}                 
     echo $fname                           
     cd $i                                       
     for z in *.mp4; do               
       echo $z  
       cp $z ${fname}_${z}
       rm $z                   
     done                                        
     cd ..                                         
  fi                                              
done
```

Comment: [Bash Pitfall #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29), [Bash Pitfall #2](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cp_.24file_.24target)

Comment: @steeldriver, the problem with this solution, it doesn't add  prefix directory to files starting with '-' and doesn't process directories containing space such as the following directory 'walking road'

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are in the directory containing all these directories `dancing`, `writing`, etc, the command

```
for folder in $(find -mindepth 1 -type d); do
  cd $folder
  PRE=${folder#./}
  for file in *; do
    mv "$file" "${PRE}_$file"
  done
  cd ..
done
```

will achieve what you want. I've tested it, and it worked even when the filenames contained spaces or newlines. It didn't work with such characters in the folder names, though, for example `walking slowly`.

**Edit:** The previous code does not handle spaces or newlines in folder names. To cover that, use the modified code

```
for folder in *; do
  if [ -d "$folder" ]; then
    cd "$folder"
    PRE=${folder#./}
    for file in *; do
      mv "$file" "${PRE}_$file"
    done
    cd ..
  fi
done
```

**Edit 2:** If a filename starts with a `-` (dash), the command may interpret it as an option. To deal with leading dashes, insert a `--` between the `mv` command and its arguments. This tells `mv` to stop scanning for options.

So the final code is

```
for folder in *; do
  if [ -d "$folder" ]; then
    cd "$folder"
    for file in *; do
      mv -- "$file" "${folder}_$file"
    done
    cd ..
  fi
done
```

Comment: @Stephan, thank you for you answer. However ,  it adds 'have_' to folder names and doesn't add prefix directory to files starting with  '-'  .

Comment: @Joseph: Replace the firsts line by `for folder in *; do` and surround the body of the `for` loop with an `if [ -d "$folder" ]` statement, just as you did in your answer. That should take care of the spaces in folder names.

Comment: The problem with your solution, it's that it doesn't process only the current directory but from  '/' root

Comment: @Joseph: I forgot to use double quotes in the `cd` statement. I really recommend reading sleeldriver's linked pages.

Comment: @Joseph: I appended a solution for how to deal with leading dashes.

Answer (score 0):

Use `find` and `prename`:

```sh
find DIR... -mindepth 1 -type f | prename -n 's/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)$/$1\/$1_$2/'
```

Remove the `-n` option to actually rename the files and not just print how files would be renamed.